# CodeBlocks vs Visual Studio react differently to same code

Tags: c++, ide

I tested this code on CodeBlocks (using C++14) and Visual Studio 2015

```
#include <iostream>

void sum(auto a, auto b)
{
std::cout << a + b;
}

int main()
{
sum(11, 5);
}
```

In codeblocks, it compiles and outputs 16 normally.
In Visual Studio, I get the error

```
  Error C3533   a parameter cannot have a type that contains 'auto'
```

I wanted to know why the compilers react differently to the same language. Also, why do you need std::cin.get() to keep the tab opened in Visual Studio, while in Codeblocks the tab won't close itself?

Comment: One is compiling C++ and the other C++ with extensions. So not the same language at all.

Comment: g++ 5.1.0: `ISO C++ forbids use of 'auto' in parameter declaration [-Wpedantic]`  Re: your last question: because IDEs are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real difference between visual studio and codeblocks is that visual studio uses its own vc++ compiler, while codeblocks uses mingw gcc, which is a port of gcc to windows.

Declaring your parameters as `auto` makes your function a *generic fuction*, something that has been proposed for some time now but hasn't made it into the standard yet. The only use-case for auto as function parameter allowed by the standard is for lambda functions (c++14, generic lambdas)

gcc does however implement support for this as an extension, since it is considered only a matter of time until this is added. Vc++ has as of yet not done this. Hopefully we will see this feature in c++20.

Generic functions are basically a shorthand for a function template with less verbose syntax.